# Substring from a file

Tags: linux, string, shell, grep

I need to extract coincidence lines from a file with a regular expression:

This is the content of file:

```
netbios-ns      137/tcp                         # NETBIOS Name Service
netbios-ns      137/udp
hkp             11371/tcp                       # OpenPGP HTTP Keyserver
hkp             11371/udp                       # OpenPGP HTTP Keyserver
bprd            13720/tcp                       # VERITAS NetBackup
bprd            13720/udp
vopied          13783/udp
```

I need to filter using `137` with `grep`:

```
grep -n -e "137" file
```

The output must be:

```
netbios-ns      137/tcp                         # NETBIOS Name Service
netbios-ns      137/udp
```

Comment: fgrep " 137/" services.txt

Comment: this is irrelevant to this question. Just mention that if you want to check what program/process is using which port, `/etc/services` file could sometimes mislead you. use `lsof` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have preceding whitespace and a trailing slash then:

```
$ grep " 137/" file
netbios-ns 137/tcp # NETBIOS Name Service
netbios-ns 137/udp
```

Or more robust, check for non-digits either side:

```
$ grep "[^[:digit:]]137[^[:digit:]]" file
netbios-ns 137/tcp # NETBIOS Name Service
netbios-ns 137/udp
```

Comment: Or even `grep -w 137 /etc/services`. Allow `grep` to wrap up the word-boundary logic for you...

Answer (score 0):

Use grep's word boundaries: `grep '\<137\>' file`